# Flip video horizontally on x- axis in objective c

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avvideocomposition

I have two play two videos simultaneously on a view .Both videos would be same.

Now, my concern is the video on right is actually to be flipped horizontally along x-axis and then saved in photo library.I have tried googling a lot and found that CGAFFineRotateTransform can help but I am not able to use that in my code.Kindly help me to flip the video on right horizontally while keeping the scale and move same.

Any help or guidance in this direction would be appreciable .Thanks in advance!

[Check the difference between video on left and right,video on left is complete but video on right is showing half video only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WWQa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just flip (mirror) the video horizontally, use a negative x-value for scaling:

```
CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale( -1.0, 1.0);
```

**Edit**: Regarding your more general question on how to position tracks: For each video track involved:

- build a bounding rect based on the original size of the track - this is the source rect
- ask yourself where the track should end up, in terms of origin and size in the resulting video - this gives you the destination rect

You can then derive the corresponding affine transform with a function like:

```
CGAffineTransform NHB_CGAffineTransformMakeRectToRect( CGRect srcRect, CGRect dstRect)
{
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    t = CGAffineTransformTranslate( t, dstRect.origin.x - fmin( 0., dstRect.size.width), dstRect.origin.y - fmin( 0., dstRect.size.height));
    t = CGAffineTransformScale( t, dstRect.size.width / srcRect.size.width, dstRect.size.height / srcRect.size.height);
    return t;
}
```

To mirror, provide a negative size for the corresponding axis (the `- fmin(,)` part compensates the offset).

Given a video track and assuming, for example, the track should go mirrored to the right half of a 640x480 video, you can get the corresponding transform with:

```
CGSize srcSize = videoTrack.naturalSize;
CGRect srcRect = CGRectMake( 0, 0, srcSize.width, srcSize.height);
CGRect dstRect = CGRectMake( 320, 0, -320, 480);
CGAffineTransform t = NHB_CGAffineTransformMakeRectToRect(srcRect, dstRect);
```

Of course this may stretch the video track; to keep the aspect ratio, you'll have to take the source size into account when calculating the destination rect.

Some remarks:

- note that in `NHB_CGAffineTransformMakeRectToRect` I deliberately chose to start with the identity matrix, and then add the required transforms one by one. This way much more complex transforms can be build, including rotation. As I said, try to get a grasp on affine transforms, they're really powerful
- `AVAssetTrack`s `naturalSize` sometimes returns confusing results for some videos with complex SAR/PAR definitions. To make this bullet proof, you'll have to derive the size from the dimensions in the corresponding format descriptions, but that's a whole new topic...

Comment: But when I use this code,the video gets smaller as the new image attached above.

Comment: Well, you asked just for mirroring, without giving any reason why you were also scaling the tracks, and especially why you were scaling unevenly along the axis, and why you used different x-scaling values on the two video tracks. You should probably take a bit of time to understand the concepts behind affine transformations and how to use them, especially with regard to concatenation.

Comment: This code mirrors well ...i am doing this first time...I have done scaling just to keep the left video on half of the view and right video on other half with that size as specified.Keeping the values same ,it didn't bring video equally on the screen.If,I am wrong ...please give some guidance.Thanks for your precious time.